# Formatting Microformat Umlauts broken in Firefox Operator Plugin

Tags: firefox, microformats, vcf-vcard, hcard

Did anybody successfully manage to correctly export a vcard from a Website containing Microformats (hcard) with this Firefox Plugin?
When doing so, I end up with weird characters instead of (german/spanish) Umlauts. While it's really easy to provide vcards as well, I would like to know if someone managed to correct the charset/character problems I am experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Does your document + hcard [validates](http://hcard.geekhood.net/)?